# How to set multiple PRAGMAs using SQLite.Net?

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, windows-10

After opening a connection to the database, I can set one PRAGMA, but the second one always fails.  How do I set these two PRAGMA's using SQLite.Net-PCL 3.1.1?  This is for a Universal Windows Platform app.

```
    public static SQLiteConnection Open()
    {
        if (db == null)
        {
            var dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, DatabaseFileName);
            db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbPath);
            db.Execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
            db.Execute("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL");
        }
        return db;
    }
```

I get a "Row" exception from SQLite immediately after the second execute statement.

*Requested Stack Trace:*

- at SQLite.Net.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
- at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.Execute(String query, Object[] args)
- at SceneLocker.Models.DBConnection.Open()

Edit: Adding a screenshot of the trapped exception:

[image: Trapped Exception]

Comment: Thank you for keeping the actual error message secret.

Comment: The exception content just says "Row".

Comment: Are you implying that you get an empty screen with nothing but the word "row"?

Comment: The edit is an improvement but in general, try to avoid pictures. The text in them cannot be googled. Please add the full text of that stacktrace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I get a "Row" exception from SQLite immediately after the second execute statement.

The "Row" exception means the statements returns a row of result, which is not supported by `db.Execute`.

As a workaround, you can use `db.CreateCommand` to execute that statement:

```
var dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "MyDB.db");
db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbPath);
db.Execute("PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE");
var cmd=db.CreateCommand("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL",new object[] { });//use db.CreateCommand
var result=cmd.ExecuteQuery<object>();//execute the command
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I marked this the answer because it clued me in to the fact the second Execute statement is returning a result.  I replaced the second Execute with ExecuteScalar<string> and it worked like a charm.